# Role issuance system

Tags: bots, discord.py

There is a command to request a role. I don't understand how to set some functions for reactions.

```py
@client.command()
async def role(ctx):

    role = ctx.guild.get_role(703596629860548643)  

    zapros_chanell = client.get_channel(729733881129074768 ) 
    zapros2_chanell = client.get_channel(703596629923725339 ) 
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Запрос роли")
    embed.add_field(name='Запросивший роль', value=ctx.message.author.mention)
    embed.add_field(name='Роль для выдачи', value=role.mention)

    embed.set_thumbnail(url=ctx.guild.icon_url)

    message = await zapros_chanell.send(embed=embed)
    await zapros2_chanell.send(embed = discord.Embed(description = f'{ctx.message.author.mention}, `запрос на выдачу роли был успешно отправлен, ожидайте его рассмотрения модерацией Discord`', color=discord.Color.purple()))
    await message.add_reaction('✅')
    await message.add_reaction('❎')
```

The bottom line is that if when you click on ✅, the role was issued and a text was written to the person in zapros2_chanell.

When you click on ❎, the person was not given a role, therefore, but a certain text was also written in zapros2_chanell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used an event called [on_raw_reaction_add](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_raw_reaction_add). Made a check to the reaction, keep in mind the will give the role to any message in the guild with ✅.It it just a proof of concept.

You can make it only accept reactions on certain channel, or even only for given message IDs

```py
@client.command()
async def role(ctx):    
    zapros_chanell = client.get_channel(729733881129074768)
 
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Запрос роли")
    embed.add_field(name='Запросивший роль', value=ctx.message.author.mention)
    embed.add_field(name='Роль для выдачи', value=role.mention)
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=ctx.guild.icon_url)

    message = await zapros_chanell.send(embed=embed)
    await zapros2_chanell.send(embed = discord.Embed(description = f'{ctx.message.author.mention}, `запрос на выдачу роли был успешно отправлен, ожидайте его рассмотрения модерацией Discord`', color=discord.Color.purple()))
    await message.add_reaction('✅')
    await message.add_reaction('❎')
    
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    channel = await client.fetch_channel(payload.channel_id)
    message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
    user = await client.fetch_user(payload.user_id)
    emoji = payload.emoji.name
    
    guild = client.get_guild(ID_HERE)
    role = guild.get_role(703596629860548643)  
    zapros2_chanell = client.get_channel(703596629923725339 ) 
    
    if user.id != bot.user.id: # bot to count itself
        if emoji == '✅':
            await client.add_roles(user, role)
            await zapros2_chanell.send(f'{user.name} has been given {role.name}')
        elif emoji == '❎':
          await zapros2_chanell.send(f'{user.name} did not want {role.name}')
```